# get last page number - web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site with multiple pages. I would like to build a function that returns the number of pages within a set of pages.

Here is an example starting page.

There are 29 sub pages within that leading page, ideally the function would therefore return 29.

By subpage I mean, page 1 of 29, 2 of 29 etc etc.

This is the HTML snippet which contains the last page information, from the link posted above.

```
<div id="paging-wrapper-btm" class="paging-wrapper">
        <ol class="page-nos"><li ><span class="selected">1</span></li><li ><a href='http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&pge=1&pgesize=36&sort=-1'>2</a></li><li ><a href='http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&pge=2&pgesize=36&sort=-1'>3</a></li><li ><a href='http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&pge=3&pgesize=36&sort=-1'>4</a></li><li ><a href='http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&pge=4&pgesize=36&sort=-1'>5</a></li><li #LIVALUES#>...</li><li ><a href='http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&pge=28&pgesize=36&sort=-1'>29</a></li><li class="page-skip"><a href='http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&pge=1&pgesize=36&sort=-1'>Weiter »</a></li></ol>
```

I have the following code which will find all ol tags, but can't figure out how to access the contents contained within in each 'a' .

```
a = soup.find_all('ol')
b = [x['a'] for x in a] <-- this part returns an error.
< further processing >
```

Any help/suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: by subpages, do you mean links to pages in the same domain?

Comment: by subpages i mean, page 2 of 29, 3 of 29, 4 of 29 and so on.

Comment: to get what is inside a, you can to a.text I think

Comment: @MarcelKlockman added answer below, you will need to do a find_all on each element in your list of ols.

Answer (score 2):

Ah.. I found a simple solution.

```
for item in soup.select("ol a"):
    x = item.text
    print x
```

I can then sort and select the largest number.

Comment: try a.text if you just want the number, I think it works (can't test with my config sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ols = soup.find_all('ol')
list_of_as = [ol.find_all('a') for ol in ols] # Finds all a's inside each ol in the ols list
all_as = []
for a in list_of_as: # This is to expand each sublist of a's and put all of them in one list
 all_as.extend(a)
print all_as
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would extract the last page number:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests


html = requests.get("http://www.asos.de/Herren-Jeans/podlh/?cid=4208&via=top&r=2#parentID=-1&pge=1&pgeSize=36&sort=-1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)

ol = soup.find('ol', class_='page-nos')
pages = [li.text for li in ol.find_all('li')]
last_page = pages[-2]

print last_page
```

Which for your website will display:

```
30
```